# IOS how to replace json data using their keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to change the following JSON.
My requirement is that I want to replace ("answer": "offlinetesing") with ("answer": "test12333") in a loop. Suppose if it is in index 0 I want to replace only for index 0 answer.

How can I achieve this?

I am using this code

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentFile1];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject1 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"jsonObject1 is %@",jsonObject1);
NSMutableArray *responsedictonary=[jsonObject1 objectForKey:@"questions"];
```

JSON:

```
{
    "currentquestion": "Define6",

    "phasecompletion": "80",
    "questions": [
        {
            "answer": "offlinetesing",
            "dmaicQuestion_ID": "Define1",
            "projectPhase": "Define"
        },
        {
            "answer": "testing",
            "dmaicQuestion_ID": "Define2",
            "projectPhase": "Define"
        }
    ],
    "questionsAnswered": 8
}
```

Comment: That means you need to replace only "answer": "offlinetesing" from first object of `questions` tag??

Comment: make a mutable copy of dict and set "answer" as  "whatever you want to set"

Answer (score -1):

following answer would be helpful to you.

```
NSArray *questionArray = [jsonObject valueForKey@"questions"];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSDictionary *tempDict in questionArray){
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[tempDicr mutablecopy];
    NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"answer"];
    if(str isEqualToString:@"offlinetesing"){
       [dict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"answer"];
    }
    [array addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: its crashing app__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f6a4899e0'

Comment: you have to make mutable copy of that dictionary

Comment: ok i tried but. still its  crashing here [tempDict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"answer"];

Comment: @SairamGogikar Actual logic is provided to you, now this is minor crash, you can solve it by using google

Comment: i didn't understand this line NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[tempDicr mutablecopy];

Comment: It is creating mutable copy of your dictionary. So with that line of code you can edit your currnet dictionary.

Comment: ok now its working but its replacing 0 index answer its showing like {
    answer = test;
    "dmaicQuestion_ID" = Define1;
    phaseQuestion = "What problem are you trying to solve?";
    projectPhase = Define;
    questionStatus = Applicable;
}

Comment: but i want to replace o index answer and need to see remain indexes answers like{
    answer = test;
    "dmaicQuestion_ID" = Define1;
    phaseQuestion = "What problem are you trying to solve?";
    projectPhase = Define;
    questionStatus = Applicable;
},  {
    answer = test1;
    "dmaicQuestion_ID" = Define2;
    phaseQuestion = "What problem are you trying to solve?";
    projectPhase = Define;
    questionStatus = Applicable;
}

Comment: @SairamGogikar I don't get you

Comment: answer replaces ofter i want see dictionary like-----{
    "currentquestion": "Define7",

    "phasecompletion": "80",
    "questions": [
        {
            "answer": "replaced answer",
            "dmaicQuestion_ID": "Define1",
            "projectPhase": "Define"
        },
        {
            "answer": "testing",
            "dmaicQuestion_ID": "Define2",
            "projectPhase": "Define"
        }
    ],
    "questionsAnswered": 9
}

Comment: Do you want to change "answer" key in each array. Am I right?

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you?